# Unexpected Shell Script errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am having errors where I am putting in code that should be working fine into a shell file and when I run it, it fails to run correctly. The error I am receiving from this is confusing me as well somewhat. Here is what I have:

```
echo "Please enter your student ID: "
read username
echo "Please enter your MySQL password: "
read -s password
db="db$username"
echo "DB username is $db"
$(mysql -D$db -u$username -p$password -se "CREATE TABLE...")
echo "That has been completed"
```

The SQL command has been truncated as this appears to have no relevance for the error.

If I run this code through putty I get this:

```
*******@csl-*******:~/tasks/SQL$ ./generate.sh
Please enter your student ID:
': not a valid identifierad: `username
Please enter your MySQL password:
': not a valid identifierad: `password
DB username is db
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '-p'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
./generate.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
That has been completed
*******@csl-*******:~/tasks/SQL$
```

(The * represent hidden values)

I am not sure what the error is with this code here. I have tried under different circumstances such as using a Mac to create the file with exactly the same file on and run it through terminal and it works fine (off the same Linux server). However I also went back to the same Mac to try and re-run the code and got the same error as shown here - even though the code hasn't changed.

> Some background information:
>   Using Putty for SSH access, Filezilla for FTP, Sublime Text for code editor. Connecting to a remote Linux server to run from.

Comment: Add your shebang.

Comment: Check your script for special characters with `cat -A script` or `cat -v script`.

Comment: Looks like potentially some DOS/Linux/Mac line ending issues too.

Comment: This output `./generate.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found` gave it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to having the wrong line ending character, which would be the case if you are running sublime in windows.

Try running `od -xcb` to find the carriage return characters. Unix expects just `\n` whereas you will see `\r\n` with windows carriage returns.

You can fix your file by running `dos2unix generate.sh`.

As per [Dannys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5867330/danny-franklin) comment below you can change the settings in sublime by going to *view > line endings > unix*.

---

**Examples:**

I copied your script and created a file using vim with unix carriage returns called `script.sh`. I then used `unix2dos` to create a file with windows carriage returns for testing and was able to recreate your error.

**Unix carriage returns:**

```
od -xcb script.sh
0000000    2123    622f    6e69    622f    7361    0a68    6365    6f68
      #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n   e   c   h   o
```

**Windows carriage returns:**

```
od -xcb windows.sh
0000000    2123    622f    6e69    622f    7361    0d68    650a    6863
      #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \r  \n   e   c   h
```

And the error from the windows script:

```
> . windows.sh

Please enter your student ID:
': not a valid identifier
Please enter your MySQL password:
': not a valid identifier
DB username is db12
That has been completed
```

Comment: Thank you and everyone else for your help. This has now solved the issue. Unfortunately dos2unix isn't installed on the system. However you can, on sublime, go to view > line endings > unix and then it will save correctly.

Comment: I've added that information above in case anyone else encounters the same issue with sublime.